# Disable jQueryUI Sortable item from being dropped in a certain area

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a kanban style drag and drop board using jQueryUI Sortable.

Each column is a **Board** and each draggable Div on the board is a **Card**.

A **Board** can have **Child-boards** which group a set of related boards under 1 **parent board**.

I am having an issue with the Drag and Drop of cards to a new board.  The problem is when a **Card** is dragged onto a Board that has child-boards and the card is dropped prematurely before entering the child-board table.

It results in the card being dropped inside the parent board `<td>` table cell but before getting to go into the child board `<table>` which is inside the parent board `<td>`.

This image should help explain a little better...

The red boxes show the HTML for the 2 Boards I have that have **child-boards**.
The `<td>` table cells above and below those boxes are regular boards with no child-boards.  A card can be dropped into those `<td>` cells.

ON the Parent boards that have child-boards.  You can see that they have a `<table>` inside of there `<td>`.

The issue is when the card gets dragged onto a board that has child-boards and the card is dropped to soon so it results in the card being in between the `<td>` and the child board `<table>`....

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUPHz.png

---

**Here is an example showing the Card that was dropped in between the parent board and the child board in a "undefined" area...I need to somehow make it not possibble to drop a card in this area!**

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yosjh.png

---

**Image showing what a Board and cards are and the child-board vs Parent with no child board**

[image]

---

**Example showing a card being dragged into the bad position and how it moves the child board table out of the way and allows a drop in between the parent and child.  I need to prevent this from happening somehow?**

[image]

---

**Perhaps there is a way to prevent jQueryUI Sortable from allowing a Drop if the `<td>` with CSS class `column ui-sortable` has a `<table>` inside of it?**

---

**Here is a quick JSFiddle to show the problem** http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/j37131oo/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to add a `class` to these `td` with child boards and set `sortable` to only the ones without this class. Something like:

```
$('.columns > table').parent().addClass('hasChildBoard');
```

And then:

```
    $(".column:not(.hasChildBoard)").sortable({
        connectWith: ".column",
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yuw2opzr/

Comment: Thanks this is my thought but wasn't sure how to call that `droppable() `part.  I added the CSS class in my backend server side for parent boards.  I also added a demo JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/j37131oo/3/ (doesnt have the new CSS class in the demo) I tried adding 
`$('td:not(.hasChildBoard)').droppable();` on my real demo but it didn't do anything.  Could be because it doesn't work with `sortable()` or I didn't add it in the correct location?

Comment: Oh, I thought they were droppable, see edit, basically the same with sortable, if you already have your class you can drop the first part. It seems to be working, but I'm not sure if I really reproduced your problem. Try and let me know.

Comment: That's perfect better than I thought was possible even!  I thought I might have to allow it to continue and then cancel the action half way through which would not be a good UI/UX.  THis is perfect as it doesn't not even allow the child table to get pushed out of the way anymore and prevents it from saving in the wrong location.  Thnaks!